# How to have both centered heading text and rightflushed image in the same line IN LATEX

Tags: includegraphics, cv, fontawesome5

I am having this :-

[image: what i have]

What I want:-

[image: what i want]

My code so far

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{passport_photo.jpeg}
   \end{flushright}
\end{figure}


\begin{center}
    {\Huge \scshape Debroop Majumder} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small
    \raisebox{-0.1\height}\faPhone\ XXXXXXXX ~
    \href{mailto:XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com}{\faEnvelope\ XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com} ~ 
    \href{https://XXXXXXXX/}{\faLinkedin\ -XXXXXXXX}  ~
    \vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: How or where is `\faPhone` defined?

Comment: I think those are just pre defined icons of phone, mail and linkedin

Comment: And where does this predefinition occur? E.g., do you need to load a package?

Comment: yes the fontawesome documentation.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631704/using-font-awesome-regular-icons-in-latex ... here you go, but the problem is not with those icons... I just want the entire thing which is centered, to be in the same line along with the right picture..

Comment: Ah, `\usepackage{fontawesome}` is needed.

Comment: yes, all the pacakges are added ... I havent included it in the code here, but if you want I can , post it here but it will make it too lengthy... and this is it `\usepackage{fontawesome5}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (The framelines around the text block are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded; don't load this package in a real document.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}     % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{showframe}      % don't load this package in real doc.
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{calc}           % simplify certain on-the-fly calculations
\usepackage{fontawesome5}   % for \faXXXX macros
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2cm} % width of photo is 2cm (see below)
\centering
{\Huge\scshape Debroop Majumder}

\small
\medskip
\faPhone\ XXXXXXXX
 
\href{mailto:XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com}{\faEnvelope\ XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com}

\href{https://XXXXXXXX/}{\faLinkedin --XXXXXXXX} 
\end{minipage}%
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{passport_photo}}}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dammn, Thanks dude. You really helped me out with my resume. You are an amazing coder.

Comment: @Khoka420 - You're most welcome.